# how to change object type into a JSON serializable object

Tags: python, json

so I've got a list of data each element is in this format

```
{
  "Account_Level": 143,
  "ActiveId1": 8844,
  "ActiveId2": 8879,
  "ActiveId3": 0,
  "ActiveId4": 0,
  "Assists": 14,
  "ret_msg": null
}
```

this data is pulled from an API wrapper so the type is `pyrez.models.Match.Match` so when trying to use `json.dump` to save the list containing this type of data I get

> TypeError: Object of type Match is not JSON serializable

EDIT: Fixed using by changing each element individually `[i.json for i in session]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable)

Comment: Bey default `json.dump` only understands very basic types like `dict`, `str`, numbers, etc. But, the [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder.default) you can extend it to serialize other types. That is, you'd pass the `cls` keyword argument as is done in the "Extending JSONEncoder" example near the top of [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this PyRez library uses some kind of custom Dict object for API responses, and the `__str__` method is already doing a `json.dump` of the args. So try `str(the_obj)`. See [here](https://github.com/luissilva1044894/Pyrez/blob/1.1.x/pyrez/models/Mixin/Dict.py).